# Spring web project deploy failed in tomcat but works in jetty

Tags: spring, tomcat, jetty

While using tomcat to deploy my spring web project,it gives me the following exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAn
notationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PI
NYIN.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/icu4j-2.6.1.jar!/] for annot
ations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in
constant pool: 60
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.
java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPoo
l.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(Cl
assParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.j
ava:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(Co
ntextConfig.java:2104)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(Conte
xtConfig.java:1980)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(Conte
xtConfig.java:1946)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextC
onfig.java:1931)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
a:1325)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
g.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5173)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.ja
va:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfi
g.java:1637)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
```

But it is working in jetty. Can anybody tell me what's the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the same issue as this one: [Tomcat 7 - Servlet 3.0: Invalid byte tag in constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751920/131929) (an old version of com.ibm.icu:icu4j).