# org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 60

Tags: spring-mvc

When I run my spring mvc project,I get the error below.

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class] from Jar [jar:file:/home/cme/priyanka/eclipse/workspace_23_10/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LIVEEVENT123/WEB-INF/lib/icu4j-2.6.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 60
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2001)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:
[Tomcat 7 - Servlet 3.0: Invalid byte tag in constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751920/tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool)

I just added(I am using maven) this dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
     <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
     <version>3.4.4</version>
 </dependency>
```